# migration not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, frameworks

I have a problem , my migration is not working, the version is added to the DB is 0 but I have configured 1 for version its not running my create table method

```
class Migration_Add_blog extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'blog_id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 5,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'blog_title' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ),
            'blog_description' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'constraint'=> '100'
            ),
        ));

        $this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id',TRUE);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('blog');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my schema version has already done so creating table wont work, so you have to rollback your schema:

```
$this->migration->version($old_schema);
```

If rollback has an error, try commenting inside of your method down(), because the table does not exist just yet.

After successfully rollback, now try migrating it again.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you  named the file correctly?

**version_fileName.php**

in your ex .

```
 001_Migration_Add_blog.php
```

---

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
$this->dbforge->add_key('id',TRUE);
```

to

```
$this->dbforge->add_key('id',TRUE);
$this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
```

---

to update the schema

```
$this->load->library('migration');

if ( ! $this->migration->current())
{
    show_error($this->migration->error_string());
}
```

or

```
$this->load->library('migration');

 if ( ! $this->migration->version(5); // or 6 , 7 your migration version
  {
   show_error($this->migration->error_string());
   }
```